# Get Form request with Seam/JSF

Tags: java, rest, jsf, seam

I have a query form that I would like to submit as a GET request so the result page may be bookmarked and otherwise RESTful. It's your classical text field with a submit button. How do I induce Seam/JSF to use GET and include the query expression as a parameter rather than POST, the default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is enable the SeamFilter in web.xml. See [Blog Example](http://docs.jboss.com/seam/2.0.2.SP1/reference/en-US/html_single/#blog) for an example RESTful application using Seam.  The key is to use a Seam page parameter, defined in WEB-INF/pages.xml

Answer (score 1):

you can use a PhaseListener to convert POST requests to GET requests or just to interpret GET requests so that they can be bookmarkable.

This page should explain in more detail:

http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/03/post-redirect-get-pattern.html

Comment: Interesting, but it seems a bit like a sledgehammer when I only need to do this for one page.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `s:button` or `s:link`, your form will be using GET method.